# Why cannot login to API-Store from Microservice?

Tags: store, wso2-api-manager

I am looking for a way to login to WSO2-AM from an application to receive Access Token. Login Rest-API has been deprecated.

I am writing a ReactJS application. I would like to login to my WSO2-AM Store (with useride / password) and generate/retrieve an access token for further use (further call of APIs) managed by WSO2-AM.

I see that WSO2-AM Store has deprecated the Login REST-API some longer time ago. What is the alternative? Neither at WSO2 nor using Google could help me so far. Thanks for a response or link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Store REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/) for API subscribing actions. This is not deprecated. [Jaggery APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Store+APIs) are only deprecated.

Comment: I have looked through the Store Rest APIs, but cannot see, how to achieve my goal: 
1. login with my userid/pw credentials into my account
2. generate/retrieve access token;
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can find the commands to get authorized under the section "Getting started" - [1]. There you can give the user's credentials (who is logging into store) in base64 encode format, it will returns relevant client-id and secret for the oauth application created for that user. Using those client id and secret, you can generate token which can be used to call the APIs to generate tokens. [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#guide

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved using the API manager REST APIs.

1. First you can create a Service provider by following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#guide) this will create an OAuth app the provide you with the clientId and secret for calling the REST APIs and  Base64 encode the ClientId and Secret you received in the following format :. and obtain an access token to begin calling rest apis. Here are some example curl requests

To register sp

```
curl -X POST \
  https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.14/register \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "callbackUrl": "www.google.lk",
        "clientName": "rest_api_publisher",
        "owner": "admin",
        "grantType": "password refresh_token",
        "saasApp": true
}'
```

To obtain access token to call REST API

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://localhost:8243/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:subscribe' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Base64(YOUR_CLIENTID:YOUR_CLIENTSECRET)'
```

note that i have here used the scope apim:suscribe, this is the scope needed to access store apis. If you want to access all the apis the url scope would be in the following format.

```
scope=apim:api_view apim:api_create apim:api_publish apim:subscribe
```

2. Since you have an access token now you can create an application using this [api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsPost) and  generate keys from this [api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsGenerateKeysPost) or if you have already created an application and generated the keys you can obtain the access token related to that from this [api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsApplicationIdGet)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
So I can receive the Bearer Token using a curl command:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:subscribe" -H "Authorization: Basic UmZJc3dIYU9zaDNlMXIycTExZk4yV3JjalhBYTplejk5MDgzdzR6ZjhHVktCMnhLdXE2UGZTc2Nh" https://example.com:8243/token
```

This is progress! 
Nevertheless I am still struggling getting there with my ReactJS application:

```
    fetch ('https://example.com:8243/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + "...as above..."
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "scope": "apim:subscribe"
   })
})

.then(response => {
    console.log ("------------------" + response.ok + "----" + response.status + "----" + response.statusText);
  })
```

"response.ok" shows false, "response.status" shows 0

Can u help me getting across this "last" thing?

Comment: try sending the data as query strings, not in the body